# Find existing player to update or create new one

Tags: java

I'm making a game in Java 7, and I have this block of logic when handling an update from the server.

```
public void handleNewPlayer(Player newPlayer, Player[] otherPlayers) {
    boolean done = false;
    for (Player otherPlayer : otherPlayers) {
        if (newPlayer.id == otherPlayer.id) {
            updatePlayer(otherPlayer);
            done = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!done) {
        createPlayer(newPlayer);
    }
}
```

The client has a list of players, and gets a player object from the server. If the client already has that player (one with the same id), it updates that existing one, otherwise it creates a new one.

This code looks ugly though. The `done` flag is really getting under my skin. Is there a better way to organize this to avoid that? Are there any other problems with this code?

Sidenote: `createPlayer()` and `updatePlayer()` do very different things, and need to be seperate methods.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @lealand Only Java 7, for android compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is a bit longer, but I think it spells out the intent and flow more clearly. One can tell what each method does at a glance, instead of having to run the code mentally.

```
public void handleNewPlayer(Player newPlayer, Player[] otherPlayers) {
    final Player existingPlayer = findPlayerById(newPlayer.id, otherPlayers);

    if (existingPlayer == null) {
        createPlayer(newPlayer);
    } else {
        updatePlayer(existingPlayer);
    }
}

private Player findPlayerById(long id, Player[] otherPlayers) {
    for (Player player : otherPlayers) {
        if (id == player.id) {
            return player;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. With Java 8 I think it could be even further improved by using an `Optional<Player>` as I mention in my review just because I hate seeing `null`s.

Answer (score 3):

A very quick review for the code, and assuming Java < 8:

```
public void handleNewPlayer(Player newPlayer, Player[] otherPlayers) {
    for (Player otherPlayer : otherPlayers) {
        if (newPlayer.id == otherPlayer.id) {
            updatePlayer(otherPlayer);
            return;
        }
    }

    createPlayer(newPlayer);
}
```

Some code styles prohibit this because you typically only want to have one return in a function (there's two here), but I typically overlook this for simple methods where the logic ends up clearer in my opinion.

And here's a Java 8 way (might not be optimal)

```
public void handleNewPlayer(Player newPlayer, Player[] otherPlayers) {
    final Optional<Player> otherPlayer = Arrays.stream(otherPlayers)
        .filter((Player p) -> newPlayer.id == p.id)
        .findFirst();

    if (otherPlayer.isPresent()) {
      updatePlayer(otherPlayer.get());
    }
    else {
      createPlayer(newPlayer);
    }
}
```

It doesn't do much on the LOC metric, but it has a much clearer semantic meaning.

A comment from Vogel612 brings up the `Optional#orElse` method. This sounds like a great method, but the only way I can see it used here is as follows:

```
public void handleNewPlayer(Player newPlayer, Player[] otherPlayers) {
    final Optional<Player> player = Arrays.stream(otherPlayers)
        .filter((Player p) -> newPlayer.id == p.id)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(newPlayer);

    if (newPlayer == player) {
      createPlayer(newPlayer);
    }
    else {
      updatePlayer(player);
    }
}
```

I think this has even greater semantic meaning, but your mileage my vary. Additionally, I still feel like we're lacking the conciseness of the final version below.

Finally, [you can now use Groovy for Android development](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin). Here's how this can be done in Groovy:

```groovy
def handleNewPlayer(Player newPlayer, Player[] otherPlayers) {
  def otherPlayer = otherPlayers.find() { newPlayer.id == otherPlayer.id }
  if (otherPlayer) {
    updatePlayer otherPlayer
  }
  else {
    createPlayer newPlayer
  }
}
```

Comment: Curious, how would you do this in Java 8?

Comment: Stream the `otherPlayers` array and filter. I haven't used the new API at all, but there's some lovely ways to handle loops and conditionals.

Comment: You don't have to accept so soon. I suggest waiting a few days for better answers.

Comment: it might be possible to use `.orElse` of Optional to simplify the java 8 version

Comment: @Vogel612 see, I didn't even know that existed. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Actually, I think that'd only work if there was a single method taking the parameter. Correct me if I'm wrong.